# Sell Limit in Exchangewallet

Tags: sell-bitcoins, money-transfer

In case BTC raises above $ 100.000 as predicted. How will it be possible to get your money out of the marked?

Does anybody nows an exchangewallet where is no or almost no limitation for sell orders???

Comment: You mean exchange btc to fiat? or withdraw fiat to your bank?

Comment: Almost all popular exchanges don't have limits on sell orders.

Comment: I mean both. BTC to fiat and then later withdrawal to bank.

Comment: Josh, coinbase is a popolar exchange and has a limit. All the others I habe checked too. Please make a suggestion which one is without a limit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a wallet where withdrawal limit is based on the BTC value rather than a USD value.

As far as I know, Poloniex has a withdrawal limit of USD

Whereas Bittrex has a withdrawal limit in BTC

The same goes for Binance

There are many other exchanges with BTC withdrawal limit. Which will make it easy for you to withdraw even if BTC value increase tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be GDAX.
There you can trade unlimited fiat/coins <--> coins/fiat even though you have a withdrawal limits. 
So you can sell BTC anytime,at any price and any volume you want.